# How to partially flatten a cube (or higger dimensional ndarray) in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, flatten

I'm trying to flatten a 3d array in numpy over an axis (that is, reducing over an axis and flattening over another)
for instance, if I have

```
X = array(
    [[[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
      [ 4, 5, 6, 7],
      [ 8, 9,10,11]],
     [[12,13,14,15],
      [16,17,18,19],
      [20,21,22,23]]])
```

I want to find the operation that turns X in this:

```
array([
   [ 0, 1, 2, 3,12,13,14,15],
   [ 4, 5, 6, 7,16,17,18,19],
   [ 8, 9,10,11,20,21,22,23]])
```

I found that in this case `np.concatenate((X[0],X[1]), axis=1)` gives the solution, however I want a more generic and efficient way to perform this operation for a N dimensional numpy array.

Comment: Can you explain when you say `N-dimensional array` , from what dimension to what dimension? I am guessing `N` to `N-1`?

Comment: @Anand, I'm looking for a generic solution, from dimension `i` to dimension `j`.

Comment: @JoãoP.Ceia Edit the question for a sample 4D array case?

Comment: @Divakar , I can create another example with code, but it is more easy If you imagine an array of cubes (or rectangles) - that is - a 4D array. If I want to reduce the 4rd dimension, I want to have the option to put it over (preselected) one of the axis of the cube (left-right side, up-down side or front-back side).

Comment: @JoãoP.Ceia I am afraid I still think listing out a `4D` array would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
>>> X.transpose(1, 0, 2).ravel()
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 12, 13, 14, 15,  4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 17, 18, 19,  8,
        9, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

Comment: Thank you @ashwini , but that solution isn't what I'm looking for. In this case the array should have a (3,8) shape

Comment: @JoãoP.Ceia Do `X.transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]*X.shape[0])` then.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary  Nice... but can you elaborate on the rule for those of us who are learning the association between transpose and reshape.  It is not covered well in the doc.